# MVC 5 app - Checkbox List using Images Instead of Label Text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an MVC app. One of the pages requires a field containing a dynamic list of checkboxes. The actual number of checkboxes to display is controlled by the number of rows in a SQL table. Each row will be a checkbox. I've figured out how to do this and display them on the page using the following code. This example contains a dynamic list of currencies, with each currency represented by a checkbox. This example displays a label next to each checkbox describing what the currency is (e.g., USD). However, what's really wanted is to display an image (which would be contained in the model as a byte[] type) instead. I'm not sure how to accomplish this since MVC doesn't support anything like an @Html.ImageFor. This might be simpler than I'm making it out to be but I can't figure out how to place an image where the @Html.LabelFor current resides.

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CurrencyList.Count; i++)
        {
            <div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CurrencyList[i].AdvertiserCurrencySupportId)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.CurrencyList[i].Checked)
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CurrencyList[i].Checked, Model.CurrencyList[i].Currency)
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: what would you be using as the source of the url for the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use a basic image tag, inserting data where needed

```
<img src="@Model.CurrencyList[i].ImageUrl">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got the byte array, looks like you want to use inline images, so you should be able to do that with plain HTML:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.CurrencyList[i].ImageBytes)">
```

But you're probably better off with a plain image pointing to a URL, since inline images can eat up a lot of bandwidth since you're pulling them every time the page loads, so you don't get any browser caching.